# call a function for :condition in association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display sent messages by the user. Problem is drafts and sent message contents are stored in the same table, so I want to put a condition on the following association from `user.rb`

```
has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "user_id",  :conditions => [#it has been sent!]
```

I thought of using a is_sent method from `message.rb`

```
def is_sent
    current_user.drafts.find_by_message_id(:first, self.id).empty?
end
```

How can i call this method in the `:condition` of my association?
Would it be preferable to use a column in my Message table specifying if the stored message has been sent or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a boolean `sent` column to `Message`, and use this condition in the `has_many`:

```
:conditions => { :sent => true }
```

This would also give you the function `sent?` in `Message`, eliminating your `is_sent` function. Note that using a question mark like that in function names in Ruby is common practice, and `is_` is frowned upon.